# value too great for base (error token is "08")

Tags: scripting

Trying to do quiz 'max sum of 2 from grid'

Can't figure out how to get around the error below.

Feels like I'm missing something.  Once I find out what I can update the question to be more general and applicable to others perhaps.

```
Line 32: value too great for base (error token is "08")

#!/bin/bash
setup () {
  grid=(01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 07 06 05
        12 13 14 15 16 15 14 13 12 11 11
        05 06 06 07 07 07 06 06 05 05 04)
  n=${#grid[@]}
  number_of_lines=$((n / 11))
  length_of_line=$1
  largest_sum=0
  largest_pos=0
}
largest_2 () {
  for ((row=0; row < number_of_lines; row++)) {
    for ((column=0; column<length_of_line-1; column++)) {
      larger_horizontal
      if [[ $row -lt $number_of_lines-1 ]]; then
        larger_vertical
      fi
    }
  }
}
larger_vertical () {
  sum=$((grid[column+row*11]*grid[column+(row+1*11)]))
  if [[ $sum -gt $largest_sum ]]; then
    largest_sum=$sum
    largest_pos=$((column+row*11))
    direction=vertical
    result=$largest_pos
  fi
}
larger_horizontal () {
  sum=$((grid[column+(row*11)]*grid[column+1+(row*11)])) # <-- Line 32
  if [[ $sum -gt $largest_sum ]]; then
    largest_sum=$sum
    largest_pos=$((column+(row*11)))
    direction=horizontal
    result=$largest_pos
  fi
}

setup 11
largest_2
printf "\n1. Max: row=$((result / 11 +1)) column= $((result % 11 +1)) direction=$direction\n"
```

Comment: You're getting a lot better at this. What's the pattern in `$grid`? I know there's one there - but I can't put my finger on it.

Comment: Thanks!  I always appreciate your help! As for the grid - actually I put the pattern there myself.  The actual grid in the problem has several hundred numbers and the example here is not an actual sample from it.  Generally I'm working through Project Euler, one language at a time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`08` starts with a 0 thus is regarded as octal in some contexts (with digits between 0 and 7, hence the error beginning at `08`). The solution: filter out the 0; if you need to output a leading 0, there's `printf %02d`.

Comment: @mikeserv Yes, but here, since the values from `grid` are read several times in the script, it may be simpler to drop the leading 0's directly from the `grid=(...)` initialization.

Comment: I think it would be, definitely. Besides that math above only works for modulo 10. To do it gnereally you need like: `$((1$n%(11$n-1$n)/10))`.

Comment: @mikeserv Parentheses are missing in your general solution. It should be: `$((1$n%((11$n-1$n)/10)))`. BTW, it seems faster than something like: `n=${n#0000000000000000}; n=${n#00000000}; n=${n#0000}; n=${n#00}; n=${n#0}`.